# Error when using exec vi

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, vi, heredoc

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
   echo "USAGE:vitest filename"
else

FILENAME=$1

exec vi $FILENAME <<EOF
i
Line 1.
Line 2.
^[
ZZ
EOF

fi

exit 0
```

I'm trying to input the Line 1. and Line 2. with Exec vi using the here doc, and commands.

When running the script it gives me the following:

```
Vim(?):Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...

Press ENTER or type command to continueVim: Finished.
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...

Vim: Finished.
```

Comment: I suggest to use `sed`.

Comment: Not `sed`, but `ed` or `ex`.

Comment: use `cat` that's what its for.

Comment: I would use what you suggest, but I have to use exec vi.

Comment: If you really have to use vi for some reason. You might need to write an expect script.

Comment: Note that if you use `exec`, the following `exit 0` is never reached. Are you sure you need `exec vi` instead of just `vi`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to start `vi` in `ex` mode, with a few minor changes to the script.

```
vi -e "$FILENAME" <<EOF
i
Line 1.
Line 2.
.
wq
EOF
```

`exec` is almost certainly unnecessary, especially since you have an `exit` command following `vi`. `exec` is used to replace the current script with the given command; it is not needed simply to execute a command.

---

A brief history of UNIX text editors:

- `ed` was the original editor, designed to work with a teletype rather than a video terminal.
- `ex` was an extended version of `ed`, designed to take advantage of a video terminal.
- `vi` was an editor that provided `ex` with a full-screen visual mode, in contrast with the line-oriented interface employed by `ed` and `ex`.

Comment: Thank you, the exec explanation is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, `ed`

```
ed file << END
1i
line1
line2
.
wq
END
```

The "dot" line means "end of input".

It  can be written less legibly as a one-liner

```
printf "%s\n" 1i "line1" "line2" . wq | ed file
```

Comment: Many `ed` commands will look very familiar to `vi` users: https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html

Answer (score 0):

#### Using sed

If I understand correctly, you want to add two lines to the beginning of a file.  In that case, as per Cyrus' suggestion, run:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
   echo "USAGE:vitest filename"
   exit 1
fi

sed -i.bak '1 s/^/line1\nline2\n/' "$1"
```

Notes:

1. When a shell variable is used, it should be in double-quotes unless you want word splitting and pathname expansion to be performed.  This is important for file names, for example, as it is now common for them to contain whitespace.
2. It is best practice to use lower or mixed case names for shell variables.  The system uses upper case names for its variables and you don't want to overwrite one of them accidentally.
3. In the check for the argument, the `if` statement should include an `exit` to prevent the rest of the script from being run in the case that no argument was provided.  In the above, we added `exit 1` which sets the exit code to 1 to signal an error.

#### Using `vi`

Let's start with this test file:

```
$ cat File
some line
```

Now, let's run `vi` and see what is in File afterward:

```
$ vi -s <(echo $'iline1\nline2\n\eZZ') File
$ cat File
line1
line2
some line
```

The above requires bash or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm pretty new at scripting so these are very valuable. Is there a way to use exec vi in this case?

Comment: @EstebanRodriguez OK.  I added a `vi` solution.

Comment: @John1024, sed has more commands than just `s///`: consider the `i` command to insert lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cat`.

```
$ cat file1.txt file2.txt | tee file3.txt
Line 1
Line 2
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```